# GUI for end-to-end tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, integration-testing, end-to-end

I'm helping an organization that has a website with some moderate-level complexity, past the point of just a bunch of static web pages but not to the point where they have a developer on staff.

To catch anything that breaks as they make website updates, I'd like to set up some automated end-to-end tests to run daily to do things like fill out a form and make sure that it takes the user to the right page, and check a dashboard to make sure it shows the right information. I could write Selenium tests, but I'd prefer to do something that they can maintain and update themselves in the future without writing code.

Are there any tools that would let a user "record" interactions with a website (or easily program them from a visual interface) and set expectations for the result, and then allow the user to schedule the test to be run on a regular basis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are, they are called low-code or no code software testing solution. I've used both [Testim](https://www.testim.io/) and [Reflect](https://reflect.run/) but honestly there are a lot of them.

So for example with reflect I can record a web application, set assertions (either based on text or on a visual element) and then I can run them either on a set schedule or based on some event like an API call.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The tools exist. The need for actual programmers remain.

If non programmers write tests, or capture interactions with a script and then run them at at scheduled intervals, they will run into the following problems.

- copy and paste will quickly lead to extensive duplications, inconsistencies, and confusion.
- dynamic elements such as id's will change from run to run
- flaky tests will emerge which will need a programmtic approach to retrying them

Programmers will run into the same problems.  They have the skills and knowledge to programatically fix them. Non-programmers do not.  Creating automated tests is developing code and requires most of the same discipline and skills as writing application code.  It's all code.

Be careful about going down the path of a poor solution with brittle, flaky long running tests that are hard to update.  Tests can quickly become a liability not an asset because they slow down development today but speed it up for tomorrow.